# How to deal with a hash table that is bigger than my computer's memory?

Tags: hash, architecture, hashtable

I have to implement a hash table of a LARGE number of entries such that I cannot put them all in memory. My thought is to put them in a file. But I don't know what to do next since the file is also huge.

Comment: look for `sharding`...

Comment: Or use a database, such as SQL.

Comment: I'll go with Glen here, once your data structures get too big for memory and unwieldy to handle as a "normal" file, a database (or some other pre-made data store) is probably appropriate.